# How can I improve Time To First Byte when using Nancy?

Tags: nancy

I'm attempting to redevelop the software that drives http://mammothworkwear.com/ using Nancy but I'm having issues attempting to get the TTFB down to under 300ms.

My prototype is hosted in IIS, built in release mode and I have removed the web.config debug flag. If you test at any of the pages on Mammoth Workwear you will see that I have the TTFB below 50ms using a hybrid .Net framework I've built and optimised over the years. How would I achieve the same with Nancy?

This is the test code I am using.

```
Get["/ttfb-test"] = _ => {
    return "<h1>Any faster?</h1>";
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had the `FormsAuthenticationConfiguration` in my Boot Strapper attached to the `RequestStartup` pipeline, which means it preformed the following on each request:

```
var cryptographyConfiguration = new CryptographyConfiguration(
    new RijndaelEncryptionProvider(new PassphraseKeyGenerator("SuperSecretPass", new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 })),
    new DefaultHmacProvider(new PassphraseKeyGenerator("UberSuperSecure", new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 })));

var formsAuthConfiguration = new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration
{
    CryptographyConfiguration = cryptographyConfiguration,
    RedirectUrl = "~/account/login",
    UserMapper = container.Resolve<IUserMapper>(),
    RedirectQuerystringKey = "url"
};
```

I moved it to the `ApplicationStartup` method so it only happens when the app first starts up, and it dropped the TTFB down to 2.2ms. Much better than I could have expected!

Loving Nancy!